# Am I able to use JavaScript with the Java SDK?

Tags: java, javascript, sdk, minecraft

I want to create a mod for Minecraft, and I am aware it uses Java. I am currently learning JavaScript, and was wondering if I am able to use JavaScript for the SDK.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes because Java has a JavaScript engine, but no because I  don't think that's what you're asking (you can't "compile" JavaScript using Java's SDK).

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

### Java is not Javascript...but a Java project can interpret Javascript

Java and Javascript are two completely different languages.  However, there is a javascript interpreter created in Java, that you can plug in to java, called [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino).  However, although Rhino makes it easier to embed Javascript into your Java code, its not a simple drop in solution that would allow you to simply script what ever you want with out going through the effort of makin the proper connections.  Definitely achievable, but you wont likely be able to start scripting without making that time investment to connect Java and Javascript.

### Background story

The relationship between Javascript and Java is a rather shallow one.  The similar name comes from a marketing plan back when it was being released by Netscape (which most developers ended up moving to the non-profit Mozilla).  They made a deal with Sun (bought by Oracle) to share that similar name, but purely for marketing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run JavaScript within a Java program, using the Rhino Javascript engine (for example).

However, this would not be a good way develop a Minecraft plugin / mod.  None of your knowledge of the Javascript APIs would be relevant.  Everything you did to interact with Minecraft would entail using Java classes and methods in the Java or Minecraft libraries.

My advice:

- If your aim is to avoid learning Java ... don't be lazy.  (You'll end up having to learn the Java APIs anyway.  And learning another language will be good for you ... assuming you aspire to be a professional programmer.)
- If your aim is to integrate some pre-existing Javascript code-base, it might work.  But you might be better off porting the Javascript code to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Java and JavaScript are totally different languages.  The "Java" in both of them was a marketing decision from ancient times.

They do share some of the same syntax that many languages share, however, so if you have learned JavaScript it might be a little easier to get started with Java.  They are definitely NOT interchangeable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JDK1.6's ScriptEngine, the interface whose methods provide basic scripting functionality. Using these methods you can execute javascript. Numerous examples can be found on usage of this.

Answer (score 0):

script support is avail from jdk 6 onwards:

[reference link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/)

However, this is not a full implementation of Rhino.